# MVC3/4 Routing and URL catching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I'm working on an MVC app and would like different customers (companies) to see different css styles, logos etc when they visit the login page (and beyond).

I thought about using a url pattern like this:

- http://www.myapp.com/CompanyA/
- http://www.myapp.com/CompanyB/

And then the routing to continue from there:

- http://www.myapp.com/CompanyB/Article/1

Then I thought I'd interrogate the URL to see which company the user is coming to the app in and load the relevant styles/logos etc.

My question is: How could I do this through routing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your route with the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
     url: "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Your action methods would then take a company parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  Assume I just extract the company name from the URL in the Request object?